# Tangent - point of contact

Tags: circles, hyperbolic-functions

Question:
Tangent to the curve $y = x^2 + 6$ at point P(1, 7) touches the circle $x^2 + y^2 + 16x + 12y + c = 0$ at a point Q. Then the coordinates of Q are:

1) $(-6, -11)$

2) $(-9, -13)$

3) $(-10, -15)$

4) $(-6, -7)$

Attempt so far:
By using differentiation, I found the slope of the tangent at point $P$, and then using the point, found the equation of the tangent. However, I couldn't solve it simultaneously with the equation of the circle as $c$ is a variable. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

As you have already calculated the equation of  the tangent

Now

**Method** $\#1:$

Find the ordinate/ abscissa of the intersection. For tangency, the two value must coincide.

**Method** $\#2:$

The perpendicular distance of the center of the circle from the  tangent =raidus

Comment: Not exactly sure about Method 1, but for method 2, notice that we don't have the value of $c$. Thus we can't find the radius of the circle :(

Comment: @Gummybears, Radius= $$\sqrt{8^2+6^2-c}$$ and the distance=?

Comment: Distance is -0.5 units.

Comment: @Gummybears, $$\frac{|2(-8)-(-6)+5|}{\sqrt{2^2+1^2}}=\cdots=\sqrt5$$ Please share your calculation

Answer (score 0):

According to the suggested, using the info from (Tangent to the curve $y = x^2 + 6$ at point P(1, 7)), slope of the tangent = … = 2

Slope of that tangent to the circle is given by $\dfrac {dy}{dx} = … = \dfrac {-(x + 8)}{y + 6}$

Since they are the same line (and thus same slope), then $\dfrac {-(x + 8)}{ y + 6} = 2$

After simplification, we have $x + 2y = –20$

There will be quite trouble to go any further because c is unknown. However, this is an MC question, the only option that fits is (-6, -7).